# Entire functions $f$ with $\sup \left| \frac{z\log|z|}{f(z)} \right| < \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question:

> Find all entire functions $f$ that satisfy $\sup \left| \frac{z\log|z|}{f(z)} \right| < \infty$ where the $\sup$ is taken over $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: z \neq 0, f(z) \neq 0 \}$. Show that your answer is correct.

I believe the answer is all polynomials with $f(0) \neq 0$. If $f$ was entire and $f$ is not a polynomial, then $f$ would have an essential singularity at $\infty$. By the Casorati-Weirstrass Theorem, this would mean that for any $n > 0$ the image of $f$ of the set $E_n = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| > n \} $ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$. In particular, for each positive integer $n$ we can pick $|z_n| > n$ such that $ 0< |f(z_n)|<1$. Then,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{z_n\log|z_n|}{f(z_n)} \right| = \infty$$

Thus, $f$ must be a polynomial. If $f(0) = 0$, then write $f(z) = a_1z + a_2z^2 + \cdot + a_kz^k$ where $a_1 \neq 0$. Observe that

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \left| \frac{z\log|z|}{a_1z + a_2z^2 + \cdot + a_kz^k} \right| = \lim_{z \to 0}\left| \frac{\log|z|}{a_1 + a_2z + \cdot + a_kz^{k-1}} \right| = \infty$$

Thus, $f(0) \neq 0$.

Is the correct answer/reasoning?

Comment: These are necessary but not sufficient conditions. What happens if $\deg(f) \leq 1$?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Then, it seems like the only other thing needed is for $\deg(f) \geq 2?$

Comment: Yep, this is the only other condition needed